# AGIC using HELM is overwriting listeners, rules etc to second AKS using a shared APP Gateway

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have two AKS (Dev and QA) that I want to share with one APP Gateway in Azure.
I deployed AGIC using HELM and enabled shared on both clusters.
Using YAML files to deploy the ingress to DEV it works great but as soon as I deploy the same for QA it gets overwritten with a defaultaddresspool.

I'm not sure if it's because I am using same domain name in the YAML for both clusters? We have different subdomains for each.

We are also using same path in each cluster but I don't think that should matter since they are two seperate AKS.

DEV yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-api
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: "wildcard-certificate"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev-api.example.com
  - http:
      paths:      
      - path: /manager/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: manager-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

QA yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-api
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/appgw-ssl-certificate: "wildcard-certificate"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: test-api.example.com
  - http:
      paths:      
      - path: /manager/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: manager-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.10.0", GitCommit:"ce66412a723e4d89555dc67217607c6579ffcb21", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.18.6"}

Used to be on Helm chart ingress-azure-1.5.2
but now using ingress-azure-1.6.0-rc1

I've also tried configuring some AzureIngressProhibitedTargets for the hostname I don't want it to touch once its created but since there are two seperate AKS I don't think it would matter.

I am expecting each YAML to create the ingress listeners, rules etc for each AKS DEV and QA.
But instead it is overwriting one with the other.

My goal is to have two AKS share one App Gateway if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I found another annotation to add to my Ingress YAML which helped my AzureIngressProhibitedTarget work correctly by not modifying what was already created.

The annotation is:
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/hostname-extension

Now I am able to use two clusters with a shared APPGW and the Ingress created by one does not affect the other.

Comment: Could you please advise,  if agic creates dedicated backend pool and backend target for each ingress?

Comment: Yes, it will create its own dedicated backend pool and backend target for each ingress. You will have to use the AzureIngressProhibitedTarget on each AKS. It was a little confusing because I had to set it up using the others hostname. Example: on QA AKS the hostname used would be the one pointing to DEV and on DEV AKS the hostname would be the one for QA

Comment: The post below from srbhatta-MSFT is what I did with the hostname-extension annotation that you are already using on the ingress.

Comment: thank you for your response. Why I'm asking because I have two identical AKS clusters (prod and qa), which are pointed via HELM to the shared App Gateway. During deployment of the same ingress (services, deployment have exact the same names in their AKS) , AGIC creates all necessary entities on AppGW level and during deployment of the ingress for the second cluster , AGIC is trying to deploy backend target into the existing backend pool (created by the first AKS). And it appears that I have one backend pool record with two backend rules and one backend target (IP of the second AKS).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can share one Application gateway between 2 AKS clusters but you have to properly configure the **AzureIngressProhibitedTarget** such that the DEV AGIC does not overwrite the QA AGIC as [defined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing#multi-cluster--shared-application-gateway). Please see the below prohibitions.
In the DEV cluster configure

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: "appgw.ingress.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIngressProhibitedTarget
metadata:
  name: test-api-prohibition
spec:
  hostname: test-api.example.com
EOF
```

In QA cluster

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: "appgw.ingress.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIngressProhibitedTarget
metadata:
  name: dev-api-prohibition
spec:
  hostname: dev-api.example.com
EOF
```

Configuring the above prohibitions should fix your issue of agic overwriting the app gateway listener configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it this way on each cluster. But as soon as I delete the ingress from one cluster it wipes out the backend pools/settings on the app gateway that were already configured. It does the same vice versa. If I also create the ingress using the yaml it first wipes what was previosly there for the backend pools/settings and creates the new ones.

Comment: I think it to be the expected behavior. Why would you want to delete the ingress from your cluster?

Comment: yes you are right that would be the expected behavior. But what I am trying to do is to have each cluster with its own ingress w/o one overiding/deleting the other. It seems the AzureIngressProhitbitedTargets don't work the way they are intended.

Comment: Oh I got you. Did you check if you have set the shared=true in the helm values, that still needs to be set.

Comment: yep, that was set to true on both clusters using HELM